# Configure TCP/IP to use DHCP and a Static IP Address at the Same Time

Tags: windows-7, networking

- My computer is configured to obtain a IP address automatically using DHCP.
- It only has one network adapter.

How to configure an additional static IP address?

I found a [tutorial](http://www.petri.co.il/configure_tcp_ip_to_use_dhcp_and_a_static_ip_address_at_the_same_time.htm) for Windows XP, but the procedure didn't work for Windows 7.

**Is it possible to configure two IP addresses on Windows 7, one being static e another being dynamic? How?**

The dynamic address I got now is 10.17.11.162. The static IP is 10.17.30.19. The network mask is the same: 255.255.224.0.
Both work independently, but I don't know how to use both at the same time.

Comment: Could you explain why having two addresses is useful?

Comment: You can't. A network card can only have a single active address.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 tools to solve this Vista/Windows 7 issue, but after a DHCP refresh or cable replug, the settings are gone.

One tool is "Win IP Config", a graphical tool to add Internet Protocol addresses. 
The other one is `iphelpcon.exe`, a command-line tool (to put into Startup folder). The second tool uses the function `AddIPAddress` of the Microsoft DLL `iphlpapi.dll`.

http://www.pkostov.com/wipcfg.html

https://anonfiles.com/file/51c4fe4b6a42f3cb450228bd0c1dd50b

Comment: Gotta say that software distributed via an anonymous file sharing site makes me *very* nervous.

Answer (score 1):

Set the interface to be DHCP, then in a command window type:

```
C:\> netsh interface ipv4 add address "Local Area Connection" 10.17.30.19 255.255.224.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. After setting to DHCP, the dynamic address 10.17.11.162 was ping'able, and the static 10.17.30.19 wasn't, as expected.
After executing "`netsh interface ...`", the static IP was reachable but the dynamic IP was gone (even on ipconfig).

Comment: ... And the GUI was again as if I had manually set the configuration to use a static IP address in it.